# How do you use a texture after releasing it?

Tags: textures, lwjgl

This may sound like an odd question, but I can't figure out textures in this situation. I am making a game for class where you get a mouse through the maze and lose if you touch a wall.

After the title screen, there is a transition where the player is directed to put there mouse onto a square before starting so that they start in the right place. This square is textured. The texture needs to be released for the maze to be drawn. After touching a wall, there is a textured rectangle filling the display for the game over screen. However, even though I tell it to bind the texture for the square before drawing it, after the gameover screen it appears untextured. How can I fix this?

```
case TRANSITION:

            IndicatorBeacon.bind();


            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex2i(50, 50); //top left 
            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex2i(50, 100); //bottom left
            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex2i(100, 100); // bottom right 
            glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex2i(100, 50); // top right
            glEnd();
            break;

 case MAZE:

            IndicatorBeacon.release();

            Maze1.draw();
            Maze2.draw();
            Maze3.draw();
            Maze4.draw();
            Maze5.draw();
            Maze6.draw();
            Maze7.draw();
            Maze8.draw();
            Maze9.draw();
            Maze10.draw();
            break;

case GAMEOVER:


            GameOver.bind();

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex2i(0, 0); //top left
            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex2i(0, 520); //bottom left
            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex2i(1050, 520); // bottom right 
            glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex2i(1050, 0); // top right
            glEnd();
            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm not right, but I think you should reload the textures.

If you don't know how to do that, I will help you with that.

If you don't have a function for the loading, do one, like that:

```java
public void loadData() {
    try {
      exampleTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",new FileInputStream(new File("res/textures/example.png")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Display.destroy();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

From now, you can reload the textures, sounds, etc.

Okay, we did the loading, but I advice you to not use OpenGL functions like that, put them into a function!

```java
public void drawStartSquare() {
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2i(50, 50); //top left 
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2i(50, 100); //bottom left
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2i(100, 100); // bottom right 
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2i(100, 50); // top right
     glEnd();
}

public void drawGameOverRect() {
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2i(0, 0); //top left
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2i(0, 520); //bottom left
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2i(1050, 520); // bottom right 
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2i(1050, 0); // top right
     glEnd();    
}
```

So, from now, you can use your statements like that:

```java
case TRANSITION:
     loadData();
     IndicatorBeacon.bind();
     drawStartSquare();
     break;
case GAMEOVER:
     loadData();
     GameOver.bind();
     drawGameOverRect(); 
     break;
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: This did the charm. I did not have the texture loading done in a function yet, and once I placed it into one I could call it to reload the textures when necessary so they could be binded again after they were released. Thank you!